# ios-charts visible data in LineChartView

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate which data indices (along x axis) are in range after panning/zooming the chart.

For example, when I zoom in on my linechart, I want to be able to update a tableview to only show the details for the data points that are visible.

I've searched the code and documentation i can find, to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

There is `highestVisibleXIndex` and `lowestVisibleXIndex` should help you. I hope I would see your issue earlier, just another weekend not on SO