# Correct way to recreate translation in ios-charts LineChartView

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am failing to correctly define the translation/center of a LineChartView when calling:

```
zoom(scaleX: CGFloat, scaleY: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)
```

I want to store the scale & center chosen by the user and then use it later to recreate the users earlier settings of scale & center.

scaleX & scaleY arrive fine from:

```
chartScaled(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, scaleX: CGFloat, scaleY: CGFloat)
```

However I am failing to get/calculate the correct displacement values of `x:` & `y:` where they are the coordinates (in pixels) of the zoom center. I've tried using `transX = lineChartView.viewPortHandler.transX` which I read when `chartViewDidEndPanning(_ chartView: ChartViewBase)` is called.

I call `fitScreen()` prior to the call to zoom so I end up with the following:

```
lineChartView.fitScreen()  // reset settings 
lineChartView.zoom(scaleX: xScale, scaleY: 1.0, x: lineChartView.centerOffsets.x + transX, y: lineChartView.centerOffsets.y + transY)
```

However this isn't working - all wisdom gratefully accepted.

using ios-charts 3.5.0, ios 14.1, swift 5

Comment: In the above the I am attempting to center by pixels, however the other method would be by Value. So does anyone know how to get the Min & Max values that the Axis is currently displaying. Should be easy!

Answer (score 1):

The original question is a duplicate of [ios-charts visible data in LineChartView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787680/ios-charts-visible-data-in-linechartview?rq=1) which I wish I'd found earlier.
So the solution, along the X axis is to record the value `LineChartView.lowestVisibleX` in callbacks `chartScaled()` and `chartViewDidEndPanning()`

then to apply the scaling with `LineChartView.zoomToCenter()` followed by the X displacement using `LineChartView.moveViewToX(lowestVisibleX)`

As yet I've not found a Y equivalent for `lowestVisibleX` so I don't have a solution for Y where `LineChartView.moveViewToY()` would be used.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: ooo, u saved my day!!! It's working great :)
whatever i tried to do ..